# Github actions `npm ci` not working with certain download

Tags: npm, next.js, github-actions

I am trying to create a CI/CD workflow that will lint and run my tests right now, I'm receiving an error from `npm ci`. The error is as follows.

```
un npm ci
  npm ci
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm ERR! Cannot read property '@auth0/nextjs-auth0' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-05-14T13_03_54_383Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The workflow Im using is

```
name: CICDNext

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  test:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 14

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
      working-directory: lms-app

    - name: Run Jest
      run: npm test
      working-directory: lms-app

    - name: Run Linting
      run: npm run lint
      working-directory: lms-app
```

The package.json is

```
{
  "name": "lms-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^2.6.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.14",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.11.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1"
  }
}
```

I'm certain I'm working in the right folder but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.